# drawable v21, v24? what is it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

When I'm creating drawables some of them goes to v21, v24 folder.

Why is this happening?
Will they appear in andoid api 15 (android 4)?
Do I need to do something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those drawable folders are actually for providing device compatibility (i.e. to manage different screen densities in android) and different android versions.