# Why do we use drawable v24 in android?

Tags: android

We have a drawable file already in drawable v21 also for ripple effect.
So why we use drawable v24 when we are getting vector file already.

Below is the xml File **ic_launcher_foreground.xml**.

```
  <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
             android:width="108dp"
             android:height="108dp"
             android:viewportHeight="108"
             android:viewportWidth="108">
        <path
             android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M32,64C32,64 38.39,52.99 44.13,50.95C51.37,48.37 70.14,49.57 70.14,49.57L108.26,87.69L108,109.01L75.97,107.97L32,64Z"
             android:strokeColor="#00000000"
             android:strokeWidth="1">
             <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                 <gradient
                     android:endX="78.5885"
                     android:endY="90.9159"
                     android:startX="48.7653"
                     android:startY="61.0927"
                     android:type="linear">
                     <item
                         android:color="#44000000"
                         android:offset="0.0"/>
                     <item
                        android:color="#00000000"
                         android:offset="1.0"/>
                 </gradient>
             </aapt:attr>
         </path>
         <path
             android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:fillType="nonZero"
             android:pathData="M66.94,46.02L66.94,46.02C72.44,50.07 76,56.61 76,64L32,64C32,56.61 35.56,50.11
 40.98,46.06L36.18,41.19C35.45,40.45 35.45,39.3 36.18,38.56C36.91,37.81 38.05,37.81 38.78,38.56L44.25,44.05C47.18,42.57 50.48,41.71 54,41.71C57.48,41.71 60.78,42.57 63.68,44.05L69.11,38.56C69.84,37.81
 70.98,37.81 71.71,38.56C72.44,39.3 72.44,40.45 71.71,41.19L66.94,46.02ZM62.94,56.92C64.08,56.92 65,56.01 65,54.88C65,53.76 64.08,52.85 62.94,52.85C61.8,52.85 60.88,53.76
 60.88,54.88C60.88,56.01 61.8,56.92 62.94,56.92ZM45.06,56.92C46.2,56.92 47.13,56.01 47.13,54.88C47.13,53.76 46.2,52.85 45.06,52.85C43.92,52.85 43,53.76 43,54.88C43,56.01 43.92,56.92 45.06,56.92Z"
             android:strokeColor="#00000000"
             android:strokeWidth="1"/>
     </vector>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drawable v21, v24? what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093515/drawable-v21-v24-what-is-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newer versions of Android Studio and only two drawable directory - drawable and drawable-v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and)

Answer (score 5):

The different drawable folders are for providing different screen densities for device compatibility and for different Android versions.

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and)